# How to use @Client

Tags: nestjs

Described here https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics#client

> Another option is to use the @Client() property decorator.
>
> @Client({ transport: Transport.TCP }) client: ClientProxy;

Where do i have to put it to make it work?

Compared to this

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      { name: 'MATH_SERVICE', transport: Transport.TCP },
    ]),
  ]
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thank @Fabian for bringing up this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options with microservice client injection, as mentioned in the docs. You can either use `@Inject('MATH_SERVICE')` in the constructor and do constructor based dependency injection, or use `@Client()` on a class property. To do the latter you would do something like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MicroserviceConsumerService {

  @Client({ transport: Transport.TCP })
  tcpService: ClientProxy;

  // rest of code
}
```

Keep in mind that with this approach, unit testing does become more difficult as you can no longer mock the dependency being injected as you would with the `@Inject('MATH_SERVICE')` approach

Comment: Thanks so much, @Jay McDoniel this worked perfectly for me.
The main app and Microservice can be serviced separately now. plus I like the fact that the connection and micro_service are loaded lazily